# Syntax error in functions.php file fails Chrome page to load on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, lamp

I'm on a LAMP installation on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
PHP version is PHP 7.0.4
I've worked on WAMP before and any kind of syntax error in the `functions.php` file led to throwing an error on the webpage.

In case of LAMP, the page doesn't even reload. Below is the attachment of the webpage
[image]

If the error is rectified, the page reloads and everything works fine. I'm unable to figure out the cause of this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is facing similar issue, then please locate these files :

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

Search for `display_errors`, by default it is set to `Off`, just change it to `On` and the issue will be solved.